# Can I jam on UMTS (WCDMA based) using my USRP 1?

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, umts

We want to jam on 3G using our USRP 1 and GNU radio, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to jam a signal, the easiest of which is obviously just to transmit over the signal you want to jam.  Since USRPs can transmit, that essentially answers your question.

Please note, however, that transmitting (and thus jamming) signals in spectrum that you don't have permission to use is illegal in almost every country in the world.  You will likely not get responses on how to do these things without giving details about what you are doing - nobody wants to enable illegal activity.

Comment: the 3G system is a WCDMA based, so just transmitting signal on its band wouldn't do a thing, also I'm student and it's not illegal for students  to work in a jammming project as lon as they doing there tests just in the uni

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The simple way is to simply jam the radio band in use. However, if you do this and the state takes exception, you have made it dead easy to find you. If you don't want to make high powered RF transmissions then you need to get a good book on UMTS and learn how a intercell handoff works when a mobile phone passes from one cell to the next. You could broadcast handoff signals causing user equipment to attempt to change cells. Since the new cell actually isn't expecting the user equipment the changeovers will fail and the phones will effectively jam each other.

If I were you I wouldn't do this without written official permission because harder to find isn't the same as impossible to find.